# best way to build a web page

Tags: html, css

I have been developing a magazine engine which behaves like a web page. Currently it is heavily dependent on a nested system of divs labelled by id's and classes to allow it to be swappable, and resize to fit the monitor of the device in question.

I recently showed this to someone, asking for feedback on how it looked, and he concentrated on how sloppy the html was.

**My question is, is it better to have a clean, unadorned html at the very beginning of the load, and build out the code to make the magazine that allows for the swiping on the different devices and click-throughs for desktop versions?**

Sorry I don't have a demo handy, I'm trying several css frameworks to gain control over the typical adventurous "let's try this" coding cycle to make it easier to understand and update for the future (an integrated creation system online, with styles a creator can modify). This latest iteration is exploring responsive image downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a magazine that allows for swiping .... but there are frameworks out there that lets you skip the HTML authoring altogether and stick with Javascript and CSS to render your application in a browser compatible manner as well as ability to show in a mobile device. Take a look at [Sencha](http://sencha.com) (ExtJS and Touch)

Comment: I tried sencha, but it was fairly bloated for my needs it also took almost two months to begin to get my head around the programming syntax, and their documentation was very sparse at the time. I've switched to jquery for the basics. Sencha was also heavily dependent on css3 for transitions, but I managed to get the main engine working on ie.

I just want to know if there is a benefit to having everything 'clean' and the nesting built within the javascript. You can see a previous iteration of the engine here:

http://stacks.acadnet.ca/reblend1/